# Как проверить нажата ли кнопка?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Как проверить, нажата ли кнопка? Пробовал так, но условия не срабатывают.

```
private void Button1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("True");
    }
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.IsPressed == true)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("True");
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы была возможность изменить цвет при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: Что б изменять цвет, можно намного проще сделать. В WPF есть триггеры событий, и там надо прописать, что при наведении мыши меняем цвет. Как это сделать....Мэтью Макдоналд wpf 4 c# очень подробно или в гугле пробей по wpf+с#+триггеры

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите стилизовать кнопку при нажатии на неё, то добавьте в стиль кнопки триггер, срабатывающий при `IsMouseCaptured == true` или `IsPressed == true`. Имейте в виду, что стандартный стиль кнопки не очень хорошо поддерживает изменение фонового цвета, поэтому кнопка будет выглядеть не так красиво, как хотелось бы.

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>
```

Ваша проверка в событии `Click` не срабатывает, потому что событие приходит после того, как вы *отпустите* кнопку.

Answer (score 2):

OnLeftMouseDown можно отловить воспользовавшись методом [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899.aspx).

`button.AddHandler(Button.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, обработчик, true);`

Кнопка проглатывает события мышки внутри себя, это позволяет всеравно эго отлавливать.

Comment: обработчик прописал но как выяснилось не с первого раза срабатывает другое событие а именно изменение цвета  customСolorP.SelectedColorChanged += new Action < System.Windows.Media.Color > (customСolorP_SelectedColorChanged);
можно ли задать для него обработчик или как сделать чтобы оно срабатывало с первого раза а не при повторном открытии формы

Answer (score 0):

Может быть по тому, что событие button click (нажатие кнопки) происходит после того как она "разожмётся" и соответственно пишет, что в тот промежуток времени она не была нажата...
и вообще зачем, нажимая кнопку узнавать, нажата ли она?
можешь например в свойство tag чтото записывать при какам либо действии, а потом просто проверять его, и делать дальше что либо....

Comment: Именно так и происходит. За Click( щелчок по кнопке ) можно посчитать комбинацию последовательных события, а именно "OnMouseDown" и "OnMouseUP". Чтобы узнать, нажата ли кнопка, надо обрабатывать лишь одно событие - "OnMouseDown".

Comment: Это ясно тогда как сделать чтобы не при выборе в comboboxe менялся цвет а при нажатии на кнопку?
         AmbientLight  ambl = new AmbientLight();

Comment: public void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Button1.IsPressed == true)
            {
                MGroup.Children.Clear();
                MGroup.Children.Remove(ambl);
               customСolorP.SelectedColorChanged += new Action<System.Windows.Media.Color>(customСolorP_SelectedColorChanged);
            }

            if (Button1.IsPressed == false)
            {
                wind.Close();
            }
        }

Comment: public void customСolorP_SelectedColorChanged(System.Windows.Media.Color obj)
        {
            ambl = new AmbientLight();
            ambl.Color = (System.Windows.Media.Color)obj;
            MGroup.Children.Clear();
            MGroup.Children.Add(ambl);
        }

Comment: Как я понял, вы хотите, чтобы в одно то же время (только при клике!) выполнялись 2 разные события (on button click,on button pressed) (кое какие подозрения..)?

Comment: Ну да возможно. Мне нужно сделать проверку, если выбрали в comboboxe цвет нажали на кнопку первый раз задать один цвет и закрыть форму, если выбрали в comboboxe другой цвет и нажали на кнопку задать другой цвет и закрыть форму.

Comment: скажите,а зачем при нажатий проверять что кнопка нажато или нет?